# Accidentally posted a question without realizing it, then posted real question

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I was in the process of asking a question and somehow submitted it when only halfway complete (and without knowing it).  I then completed the question and hit submit, leaving SO with 2 nearly identical questions.

The real question ([Rails nested_attributes with three way has_many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465195/rails-nested-attributes-with-three-way-has-many)) was then closed (by [Kev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419/kev)) as a possible duplicate of the accidental (and incomplete) post.  I have since hit delete on the junk post, but how do we get the real question reopened as this it was closed not because it was a bad question, but because I messed up.

Comment: You can edit the first post and undelete it yourself.

Comment: But undeleting a question [needs some magic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101361/how-do-i-undelete-my-question/132859#132859), @Martijn.

Answer (score 5):

If you still have the deleted post open in your browser, you will be able to undelete it yourself.

> [image]

You could then edit it to match the completed post. However, if you've closed the window you won't be able to do this.

Instead, just flag the deleted post for a moderator. Select the "other" flag type and explain what happened.

> [image]

Since the "duplicate" post has already been deleted, you shouldn't have any trouble getting the other post re-opened.

Comment: If one knows the URL, one can undelete; see [How do I undelete my question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101361/how-do-i-undelete-my-question/132859#132859)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is flagging for moderation attention, explaining what happened. For this specific question, it would probably be not necessary, as it already got 4 votes to re-open it.

Consider that the number of your questions that are deleted (from you, or other users) is used to determine if you are banned from asking further questions. It is not the only parameter that is checked, though; having deleted question is not a reason for being question-banned.
What you can do in similar cases, is editing the question that was not closed, and completing the question. In this way, you don't need to delete any question.